# Joining multiple times results empty

Tags: mysql

the following Query doesnt work correctly if I use the first and the second join in one query. If I join them seperately, I get proper results (see Appendix).

**1st + 2nd Join in one query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.prd_name, f.prd_id from tbl_prd as f

INNER JOIN tbl_prd_template_field_rule as f18_0 on f.prd_id=f18_0.prd_id AND f18_0.prd_template_field_id='18' AND f18_0.prd_template_field_rule_value='CF+CFast'
INNER JOIN tbl_prd_template_field_rule as f18_1 on f.prd_id=f18_1.prd_id AND f18_1.prd_template_field_id='18' AND f18_1.prd_template_field_rule_value='CF'
```

Why is that? I thought I can join those two quantities into one quantitie...

**Appendix**

**1st join:**

```
INNER JOIN tbl_prd_template_field_rule as f18_0 on f.prd_id=f18_0.prd_id AND f18_0.prd_template_field_id='18' AND f18_0.prd_template_field_rule_value='CF+CFast'
```

**Which results in:**

Canon EOS 5Ds R Body 50,6MP | 5325

Canon EOS 5Ds Body 50,6MP | 5326

Canon EOS 1DX Mark II Body 20,2MP. | 5802

Nikon D5 Body 20,7MP | 6162

**2nd join:**

```
INNER JOIN tbl_prd_template_field_rule as f18_1 on f.prd_id=f18_1.prd_id AND f18_1.prd_template_field_id='18' AND f18_1.prd_template_field_rule_value='CF'
```

**Which results in:**

Canon EOS 5D Mark IV  Body 30,4MP | 5965

**Both together:**

*Empty result*

Comment: Looks like you have to use outer join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an outer join instead. The inner join is going to return only those items matching all conditions.

Comment: How to create an outer join in mysql? I saw that there is not really such a mysql-command.

Comment: You'll be able to find plenty of information regarding outer joins with a web search. Very short version: an outer join will return a result as if it were an "or" equation as opposed to inner joins which function more as an "and". The usage is the same as your inner join example. You may get the results you want simply by replacing "inner" with "outer".